# globbing files autogenerated by a sub_directory binary

Tags: cmake

I have the following problem, I have a separate cmake project that generates `c++` files and I want to glob them into a library that uses them. Right now this is done in this manner

```
add_subdirectory(generator)
add_custom_target(run-generator ... byproduct GENERATED_FILES)
include(files.txt) 
target_link_libraries(library ${GENERATED_FILES})
```

The include files.txt is actually a  `set(GENERATED_FILES all_autogen_files)`, right now they're fixed but in the future they might change. That is what I would want to have is something like

```
add_subdirectory(generator)
execute_process(generator_binary ... commands)
file(glob ${GENERATED_FILES} output_location_of_gen_files) 
target_link_libraries(library ${GENERATED_FILES})
```

As I understood execute_process runs on the spot is read, so this would generate all the files before the `file(glob)` but I don't know how would I go about actually *building* the generator binary before the execute process, since right now what builds it before is that it is a dependency on the `target_link_libraries`

Answer (score 1):

The only way this could possibly work is if you create a [superbuild](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/), i.e. a CMake project that builds everything with `ExternalProject`s. The reason is that you can't create new targets or add sources to existing targets during the build.

With a superbuild you need at least 3 separate CMake projects: One that builds the generator and then generates the files, one that globs the generated files and builds the rest of your build artifacts, and the superbuild project that adds both with `ExternalProject_Add`. By setting the dependencies correctly you can then ensure that the project that uses the generated files is configured after the generating project has been built.

However, [globbing in CMake is discouraged](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) anyway, so listing the files explicitly is the proper way to do it. If your code-generator starts generating new files then they should be added to the list manually in the same commit, as otherwise even with `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` it is not guaranteed that the new files will be built when using globbing and the `ExternalProject` approach.